# How should I go about making a login system for video game high scores?

Tags: website-design, user-behavior, login, registration, games

I have a couple video games on my website, and to be able to add account-based features I'm implementing a login system for my site. My goal with the login system is to allow users who aren't logged in to be able to do as much as possible to avoid needlessly annoying the user.

The problem I've run into, however, is if I should require logging in to post high scores on any of my games. Because if the user does not want to make an account then they won't submit their high score, but if I allow anonymous high scores people can pretty easily spam the scoreboard (even if I use cookies to track them, they can clear cookies or use other browsers/PCs) and I'd have to clean it out. They can still play the game without logging in, but I'm not sure if they should have to log in to post their score. Another possible issue is if a user gets a few high scores and THEN gets an account, then the scores would have to be transferred somehow which could get confusing.

Are there any solutions to this that I'm missing? Or are these my only options?

Comment: Do the users really have to post their own scores? Ideally, that should be done for them. You can make a distinction between anonymous and authenticated users in **claiming** their score. That way the score is already there and there's an incentive to create an account to claim it.

Comment: Well, currently I have them type in a name they want and then it posts the score for them, but this has caused some spam to occur. With the new system it would automatically post them if you're already logged in. I think what you're saying is pretty similar to what Ahsan is saying in his answer, I'm just not sure if it would be confusing to users

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, use fear of loosing with gamification or ranking to prepare user to create his account...

How this can be achieved

**Step 1)** Let the user post his score, (Don't restrict your user to register before posting score)

**Step 2)** Then show his score with ranking like you are at 19th place in all Europe (Engage him with comparative stats)

**Step 3)** Then politely ask, enter your email to save your score and make your name permanent on top gamers board of all time *(this will be a button)*...
You can also use here something like "Authenticate your score"

**Step 4)** Also make a small link saying, *"save anonymously (This score might get lost)"*

In this way, it will not look difficult to register...Once user puts his email, send him login info to login to site

Here are two Visual Solutions, i am using some fun wording (You can improve more)

[image: One solution]

One direct approach for asking both email and name at same time

[image]

Comment: I like this, the only catch is for their score to be posted they need some kind of username. I guess I can show a preview of where they would be if they did post. This is probably close to what I'll end up doing if a better idea doesn't come along

Comment: A preview is good, or you can also generate made-up names for anonymous users. You can have some fun with the names and at the same time promote a sense of community. You can choose to keep anonymized scores in the system or you can automatically expire them. If the user decides to create an account to claim the score, automatically change the name to their chosen username.